# Is it possible to wrap a function from a shared library using F2PY?

Tags: python, numpy, distutils, lapack, f2py

I'm developing a package that requires Python bindings for the [`dgtsv` subroutine](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/db3/dgtsv_8f.html) from the LAPACK Fortran library. At the moment, I'm distributing the Fortran source file, `dgtsv.f`, alongside my Python code, and using `numpy.distutils` to automatically wrap it and compile it into a shared library, `_gtsv.so`, that is callable from Python.

Here's what my `setup.py` file looks like at the moment:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension, build_ext
import os


fortran_sources = ["dgtsv.f"]
gtsv = Extension(
    name="pyfnnd._gtsv",
    sources=[os.path.join("pyfnnd", "LAPACK", ff) for ff in fortran_sources],
    extra_link_args=['-llapack']
)

setup(
    name='pyfnnd',
    py_modules=['_fnndeconv', 'demo', '_tridiag_solvers'],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext.build_ext},
    ext_modules=[gtsv],
)
```

Note that in order to actually use `_gtsv.so`, I still have to link against a pre-existing LAPACK shared library (`extra_link_args=['-llapack']`). Since this library should already contain the `dgtsv` subroutine, it seems to me that it would be cleaner to just wrap the function in the existing shared library, rather than having to distribute the actual Fortran source.

However I've never come across any examples of using F2PY to wrap functions that are part of a shared library rather than just raw Fortran source code. Is this possible?

Comment: what do you think of the answer by @cronos ? Any reason why you cannot use ctypes?

Comment: @DebanjanBasu Yes, `ctypes` will do the trick. For some reason it never occurred to me - I suppose I was stuck in the mindset that I would need some Fortran-specific method in order to wrap a Fortran shared library. Oh well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just need ctypes, there is a complete example on calling a `lapack` function on this page: http://www.sagemath.org/doc/numerical_sage/ctypes.html

You get your function like this:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
lapack = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("lapack"))
dgtsv = lapack.dgtsv_
```

Comment: Cheers - that was a lot simpler than I thought it would be! I'm going to accept your answer, but I'll wait until the end of the bounty period to award it just in case anyone else has any good suggestions.